# TS, DDD: Value Object and factory

Tags: typescript, domain-driven-design

I created this aggregrate and this value object just to illustrate the doubt, my value object does not have validations yet

**Aggregrate:**

```
export class Person extends Entity<{name: PersonName}> {
  private constructor(name: PersonName, id?: string) {
    super({name}, id)
  }
  public static build(
    name: PersonName, id: string
  ): Either<IErrorModel[], Person> {
    const person = new Person(name, id)
    return right(person)
  }
}
```

**Value-Object:**

```
export class PersonName extends ValueObject<IName> {

  public static maxLength: number = 30;
  public static minLength: number = 4;

  private constructor(props: IName) {
    super(props)
  }

  public get fullName(): string {
    return `${this.props.firstName} ${this.props.lastName}`
  }
    public get firstName(): string {
        return this.props.firstName
    }
    public get lastName(): string{
        return this.props.lastName
    }

    public static build(props: IName): Either<IErrorModel[], PersonName> {
        const name = new PersonName(props)
        return right(name)
    }

}
```

I have a question how should I create my factory in my aggregrate
an example I have my object of value: Name, I must create and validate this object of value in the factory of my aggregrate and, or I must create in the service for example

on my aggregrate factory:

```
export class Person extends Entity<{ name: PersonName }> {
  private constructor(name: PersonName, id?: string) {
    super({ name }, id)
  }
  public static build(
    { lastName, firstName }: { firstName: string; lastName: string },
    id: string,
  ): Either<IErrorModel[], Person> {
    let errors = [] as IErrorModel[]
    // others validations
    const name = PersonName.build({lastName,firstName})
    if(name.isLeft()) errors.push(...name.value)
    const person = new Person(name.value as PersonName, id)
    return right(person)
  }
}
```

or for example in my person service:

aggregrate factory:

```
  public static build(
    name: PersonName, id: string
  ): Either<IErrorModel[], Person> {
    const person = new Person(name, id)
    return right(person)
  }
```

service:

```
export class PersonService{
  execute(req: any) {
    let errors = [] as IErrorModel[]
    const {lastName, firstName} = req
    const name = PersonName.build({lastName,firstName})
    if(name.isLeft()) errors.push(...name.value)
    const person = Person.build(name.value as PersonName, v4())
  }
}
```

My doubt is:
should i create my valuables at the agglomerate factory, or elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  public static foo( ... ): Either<IErrorModel[], Thing>
```

The name I would use for this pattern is `Parser` (see [Parse, Don't Validate](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/), by Alexis King).

A parser will typically have a dependency on the domain model, but won't normally be *of* the domain model; it's form and function are similar to that of a REPOSITORY.

In particular, we're trying to avoid, where possible, polluting our domain model with concerns that are not themselves of the domain.

A thought experiment that might make the distinction clear -- imagine that we had, say, one thousand different input messages that needed to be parsed into a Person.  We wouldn't want to have one thousand different parsers in our domain model: the parsing code would overwhelm everything else.  Instead, we'd want to have a specialized parser for each of the one thousand input messages.  If we keep the implementation of the parser near the input message, rather than near the domain, then (a) we keep the parsing code out of the domain and (b) it's much easier to figure out how each parser is being used, and what conditions are necessary to sunset the parser altogether.

Comment: Hello thank you so much, I was a little doubtful, but I think you understand, is it better to leave the creation of my value object with the parse pattern outside my aggregate? Is it better? and from what I understand this pattern replaces validation?

Comment: Ahh if you can help me, would it be "ugly" to use validation by compisition in my aggregrate?

passing it through params from my aggregrate factory?

Comment: I would pass completely parsed values to your aggregates

Comment: thanks, so i must create them on my service and send them completely parsed to my domain, thank u so much.